# How to replace the colons in this text using Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a file which looks like

```
1::12::33::1555
1::412::1245::23444
```

and so on. I need to get rid of the last argument, and replace the colons with commas. I have tried:

```
  myfile = open('words.txt', 'r')
  content = myfile.read()
  content = re.sub(r'(.+)::(.+)::(.+)::(.+)', "\1,\2,\3", content)
  myfile = open('words.txt', 'w')
  myfile.write(content)   
  # Close the file
  myfile.close()
```

but the back reference doesn't work, and I just end up with a file with commas..

What I'm hoping to achieve is:

```
1,12,33
1,412,1245
```

Comment: Please add some expected outputs as well.

Comment: `my_string.replace("::",",")` ? wont work?

Comment: Not Perl, but still relevant: http://xkcd.com/1171/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give you the string you need:

```
line = '1::412::1245::23444'
line_list = line.split('::')
new_line = ','.join(line_list[:-1])

print new_line
>> 1,412,1245
```

Answer (score 7):

Backreferences will only be interpolated with a raw string.

```
re.sub(r'(.+)::(.+)::(.+)::(.+)', r"\1,\2,\3", content)
```

You could also do this using purely strings/lists

```
"\n".join([",".join(y.split('::')[:-1]) for y in content.split("\n")])
```

Comment: You mean a [raw string](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)?

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to do it using sub though? split works great too.

Comment: @Siddhartha my first code block shows you how to do it with `sub`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [CSV library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) like so (embedding the CSV for simplicity):

```
import StringIO
import csv

t = """1::12::33::1555
1::412::1245::23444"""

f = StringIO.StringIO(t)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=':')
for row in reader:
    print ",".join(row[0:-1:2])
```

This outputs:

```
1,12,33
1,412,1245
```

Comment: Nice I hadn't heard of that library.

Comment: `",".join(row[0::2])`.  Seems like a poor fit for the `csv` module.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, I'm actually trying to do two things at once here, change the joining char and drop the last element, so `",".join(row[0:-1:2])` could work

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use simple string functions?

```
line = '1::412::1245::23444'
s = s.replace('::',',')
# content stored in a list
content = s.split(',')[:-1]
```

Comment: This does not account for the fact that the file is read in as a block and has multiple lines

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.6:

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    with open('words_out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            new_line = ','.join(line.split('::')[:-1]) + ','
            out_file.write(new_line)
```

In Python 2.7 >

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as in_file, open('words_out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        new_line = ','.join(line.split('::')[:-1]) + ','
        out_file.write(new_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you truly need regex for this. What I would do is split the line using `::` as a delimiter, then drop the last item and re-insert commas.

```
myfile = open('words.txt', 'r')
content = myfile.read()
numbers = [int(s) for s in content.split("::")]     #get a list of numbers from the string
numbers = numbers[0:-1]                             #drop last number
content = "".join([str(n) + ",," for n in numbers]) #coalesce numbers back to string
myfile = open('words.txt', 'w')
myfile.write(content)   
myfile.close()
```